# `var` comes as undefined but can't understand why

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror, var

I have been trying to understand why my js code which was inside the HTML is not working now that it is in an external file. English is not my first language which makes me even harder to understand (and spanish results haven't been quite productive as I hoped).

I literally copy-paste the code to the other file and placed `<script src="core.js"></script>` to get the js loaded but both Firefox and Chrome keep telling me `"TypeError: eng is undefined"` when it is.

**Before anyone tells me, it was already responded to in other questions, yes, I saw it was. But I don't understand anything so if anyone could explain me like "JS for dummies" would be REALLY appreciated.**

The code is:

```
//SETS "LOCALE" "EN" TO REDIRECT TO ENGLISH
(function (){
  'use strict';

 var eng = document.querySelector('.eng')

  function setLocalStorage(){
     eng.addEventListener('click', () => {
      localStorage.setItem('locale','en')
    })
  }
  setLocalStorage()

}());

//SETS "LOCALE" "ES" TO REDIRECT TO SPANISH
(function (){
  'use strict';

  var esp = document.querySelector('.esp')

  function setLocalStorage(){
     esp.addEventListener('click', () => {
      localStorage.setItem('locale','es')
    })
  }
  setLocalStorage()

}());

//GETS THE "LOCALE" AND REDIRECT
(function () {
  'use strict';

  const locale = localStorage.getItem('locale');

  if (locale === 'en') {
    window.location = 'eng.html';

  } else if (locale === 'es') {
    window.location = 'esp.html';

  } else {
    // first visit:
    document
      .querySelector('.eng')
      .addEventListener('click', () => {
        localStorage.setItem('locale', 'en')
      });

    document
      .querySelector('.esp')
      .addEventListener('click', () => {
        localStorage.setItem('locale', 'es')
      });    
  }

}());
```

Comment: Where is this script in relation to the rest of the HTML?

Comment: I think you should defer the loading of the script responsible for this js code if not already done so.

Comment: @user4642212 the this script basically identifies two CTAs and tells them to add to localStorage the values "locale", "en" or "es" so when one of those is clicked, the page from now on, whenever the index is loaded, it will take you straight to the chosen language. Is this what you asked?

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212). I see your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61982882/4642212) has a CodePen link in the answers and comments. Please be aware of this: [Why does this simple JSFiddle not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7043649/4642212).

Comment: Is your script runned before or after the body of html being loaded?

Comment: @itu _“sorry, what”_ — [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) your `<script>`.

Comment: @innis uh I haven't set such thing

Comment: @user4642212 ohhh ok, I'll test it out

Comment: @itu _“I haven't set such thing”_ — Yes, you have, because you _“literally copy-paste the code to the other file”_. So _where_ did you put your `<script>` and _where_ did you put the rest of your HTML? The _order_ is important here, as three of the posted links so far have point out.

Comment: @user4642212 ok, so now the script seems to be working, but the console still throws "TypeError: eng is undefined". Why is it working if the console shows an error?

Comment: @user4642212 oh ok, I thought it had to do with something like preload. I placed it in the head, below the CSS and font links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually according to your code you are accessing the `DOM` element and further you are calling them to do some task. But suppose you are trying to access some unavailable `DOM` content and then telling them to do something. In that case if you are trying to access some `DOM` but javascript couldn't find that it will return `undefined`. That's why you'll get `undefined`. (i'm trying to explain it easily)

Please make sure you have some elements with the class name `eng` and `esp`.

So, to overcome this case you need to check if you can access them and then give some task to do.

Suppose i'm checking here if `eng` is present there and then assigning some task to it.

```
eng && eng.addEventListener('click', () => {
    localStorage.setItem('locale','en')
})
```

Full Code is here.

```
//SETS "LOCALE" "EN" TO REDIRECT TO ENGLISH
(

    function (){
      'use strict';

     var eng = document.querySelector('.eng')

      function setLocalStorage(){
         eng && eng.addEventListener('click', () => {
          localStorage.setItem('locale','en')
        })
      }
      setLocalStorage()

    }());

    //SETS "LOCALE" "ES" TO REDIRECT TO SPANISH
    (function (){
      'use strict';

      var esp = document.querySelector('.esp')

      function setLocalStorage(){
         esp && esp.addEventListener('click', () => {
          localStorage.setItem('locale','es')
        })
      }
      setLocalStorage()

    }());

    //GETS THE "LOCALE" AND REDIRECT
    (function () {
      'use strict';

      const locale = localStorage.getItem('locale');

      if (locale === 'en') {
        window.location = 'eng.html';

      } else if (locale === 'es') {
        window.location = 'esp.html';

      } else {
        // first visit:
        document
          .querySelector('.eng')
          .addEventListener('click', () => {
            localStorage.setItem('locale', 'en')
          });

        document
          .querySelector('.esp')
          .addEventListener('click', () => {
            localStorage.setItem('locale', 'es')
          });    
      }

    }());
```

Comment: `eng && eng.addEventListener` isn’t really best practice. Use `if` instead and ensure that your DOM is loaded.

Comment: This... Actually worked! No console errors and it works smooth! Awesome! Thank you very much! And everyone who came immediately to help!

Answer (score 2):

This line of JavaScript:

```
var eng = document.querySelector('.eng')
```

is trying to access an element on the HTML page, which probably looks like this:

```
<div class="eng">english text here</div>
```

In order for the JavaScript code to find that HTML element, the page must already be loaded before the JavaScript line of code runs. If not, the `document.querySelector('.eng')` expression will return null.

To improve the chances that the HTML will be loaded and available before the JavaScript runs, it is a good practice to put your scripts at the bottom of the `<body>` element. Something like this:

```html
<body>
  <div class="eng">english text</div>
  <script src="myjavascript.js"></script>
<body>
```

But that's not a complete guarantee. To further improve your chances, you can add the `defer` attribute to the script tag, which prevents the script from running until after the page has loaded.

```
<script src="myjavascript.js" defer></script>
```

---

**Issue #2 - Hoisting**

There's a further problem with the JavaScript code that can cause an error. This has to do with "hoisting", where variables and function declarations are "hoisted" to the top of their blocks.

This JavaScript involves some hoisting:

```js
function () {
  'use strict';

  var eng = document.querySelector('.eng');

  function setLocalStorage () {
    eng.addEventListener('click', () => {
      localStorage.setItem('locale', 'en');
    });
  }

  setLocalStorage();

}
```

Because of hoisting, it's actually doing this:

```js
function () {

  // declare 'eng' as undefined
  var eng; 

  // declare setLocalStorage
  function setLocalStorage () {

    // JavaScript interpreter says during declaration:
    // "TypeError: I don't know what 'eng.addEventListener' is"

    eng.addEventListener('click', () => {
      localStorage.setItem('locale', 'en');
    });
  }

  // set 'eng'
  eng = document.querySelector('.eng');

  // now that 'eng' is set, call setLocalStorage
  setLocalStorage();

}
```

The fix - don't use an unset variable in a hoisted function. This code does the same thing, without any hoisting problems:

```js
(function () {
  var eng = document.querySelector('.eng');

  eng.addEventListener('click', () => {
      localStorage.setItem('locale', 'en');
    });
})();
```

Comment: I have both added the script at the end of my body element and set defer, still I get the same issue... It works, but the console still tells me "TypeError: eng is undefined"

Comment: @itu You're seeing that TypeError because of "hoisting". `var eng` is declared at the beginning of the function, before it is set, and since `setLocalStorage` accesses `eng.addEventListener`, it throws an error. I'll explain further in my answer above.